# How to revolve flat object by twisting it 360 to make it 3D?

Tags: modeling

I created this shape in Illustrator and imported the SVG into blender. I want to rotate the flat object by 360 degrees over the Z-Axis to make the object round.I would be pivoting the bend over the flat edge.

I tried creating an empty and adding a twist modifier to and twist over the empty. I also tried adding a simple deform modifier.

My blender object

[image: Blender object]

What I want it to look like

[image: 3D example final result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right of the bat, using an .svg for this purpose is not a good idea, because you're creating a lot of unnecessary topology. You should rather create a circle/cylinder and work your way from there.

But since you asked, I recommend the spin tool in Edit Mode:

[image: Spin]

Comment: You can also use the "Screw" modifier set to the "Z" axis and an angle of "360" if you want to go non-destructive. Remember to apply rotation before (CTRL - A).

Comment: Can you elaborate on this extra topology you are worried about? Can't both approaches end up with identical models?

Comment: @Matt I was refering to using an actual .svg file as a base model. The only way I'm aware of creating/using them is, in short, creating a picture and letting Blender draw an edge between every pixel, thus creating an absurd amount of vertices.

Comment: @Zagstrug SVG is a vector format, there are no pixels. I just tested importing a similar SVG to the one in the OP and it only ended up in blender with the handful of nodes that I had originally drawn. I think your excess topology fear is unjustified.